# how to check if limit exists for the following problem

Tags: limits

I need a step by step exploration for showing that $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\int_0^{(x-1)^4} \sin(t^3)\, dt}{(x-1)^{16}} = \infty.$$

Comment: It would help to typeset your problem using MathJax. See this [introduction](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You're new here, so let me tell you how it looks: You're just dumping a homework problem here, hoping that someone takes the bait and does your problem for you with zero effort on your part. I'm sure that's not the case, so please show some effort, some thought, some ideas, some context, something ...

Comment: What makes you think the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: Moved to comments due to nonsensical downvotes: The limit is not $\infty$. We may replace $x$ with $1+z$ and recall that in a neighbourhood of the origin we have $\sin w=w+o(w^2)$, hence

$$ \frac{1}{z^{16}}\int_{0}^{z^4}\sin(t^3)\,dt = \frac{1}{z^{16}}\int_{0}^{z^4}\left(t^3+o(t^6)\right)\,dt = \frac{1}{z^{16}}\left[\frac{z^{16}}{4}+o\left(z^{28}\right)\right]$$
and the wanted limit is indeed $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can apply L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

@Jack D'Aurizio's comment works fine. However, I don't like approximations as well as more straightforward ideas. So, here it is using L'Hopital's Rule. $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\int_0^{(x-1)^4} \sin(t^3)\, dt}{(x-1)^{16}}\to\dfrac{0}{0}$$
Use L'Hopital a couple times (twice) and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\int_0^{(x-1)^4} \sin(t^3)\, dt}{(x-1)^{16}}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ \sin((x-1)^{12})\cdot4(x-1)^3-0}{16(x-1)^{15}}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{ \sin((x-1)^{12})}{4(x-1)^{12}}=?$$
I'll leave the last 2-3 steps for you to do as they are very straightforward.